# log4j corrupts several cyrillic characters in log

Tags: java, log4j, go-cd

We are using `GOcd CI/CD` in our project. Several build and test packages print output in a console, but several cyrillic characters are corrupted in this log (check the attached screenshot). During the investigation I found, that this log is written by `log4j` library. Trying to set `UTF-8` everywhere, but still I get these corrupted characters :(

FYI, using Windows agents for these jobs

Has anyone faced with the same problem? Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

[image: log file and corrupted characters]

Comment: Are you sure it is related to log4j and not your log reader which does not supports UTF-8? Did you try to open a portion of your log into a program like Notepad++ (windows), gEdit (Linux) or SublimeText?

Comment: @ruffp Yes, this screenshot is from Notepad++. File encoding is UTF-8. the strange thing is that some cyrilic characters display correctly

Comment: You said `Trying to set UTF-8 everywhere` is it including the jvm settings?

Comment: @ruffp JVM settings, lod4j setting, Windows console settings